# Should Git track the "typings" folder? (typings.json)

Tags: git, typescript, typescript-typings

I wonder whether or not my Git should track the files in the `/typings` folder.

This folder is created by running `typings install` (I guess), and seems to be automatically created when running `npm install`. See https://github.com/typings/typings

Since it is generated content I believe we **should not** track it, but I'd like to have some feedback about it. Thanks!

Comment: it really depends on the needs of your project. Apart from that it's primarily opinion based, and I'll vote to close the question for that reason.

Comment: What could be the advantage of tracking it? In what case may you need to do that?

Comment: just as an example, a restrictive automated build environment that does not allow you to download files during build. There could be a hundred other reasons to do it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since it is generated content I believe we should not track it, but I'd like to have some feedback about it.

I *always* check it in. Until it's a part of `npm`, that is what I do. Also helps me overcome *bad definition files* and chug along with **my project**. (e.g. [Change type imported from typings definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374736/change-type-imported-from-typings-definition/37381311#37381311))

Comment: This makes sense actually. Because it does happen that we need to update a typing file. But at the same time, if we run the `typings install` again, we will loose all our changes. Wouldn't it be better to make such changes in another (and tracked) directory?

Comment: I follow the same workflow as Basarat. It is definitely helpful during the development process and until Typings become more standardized and properly versioned/maintained this will be the way to go for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 10):

You should think of **typings** folder as **node_modules** folder for TypeScript, therefore it shouldn't be checked in. If you want to simplify your build, add

```
{
   "scripts" : {
      "postinstall": "typings install"
   }
}
```

to your *package.json* file then typings install will run automatically when your run **npm install**. Don't forget to check in your *typings.json* though.

Comment: Just note that this will be executed even when someone else installs your package as a dependency.

Comment: This should probably be `prepublish` (which would run on local `npm install`), not `postinstall` for the reason mentioned by @Demurgos.