# Change type imported from typings definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm just getting started with Typescript and am trying to get the compiler to let me do `replServer.context.something = 123` in the following:

```
import repl = require('repl');

let replServer = repl.start({
  prompt: '>> '
});

replServer.context.something = 123;
```

but it's complaining with: "Property 'context' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter'".

I have installed the type definitions with `typings install dt~node --save --global` and the `repl` module is defined as follows in `typings/globals/node/index.d.ts`:

```
declare module "repl" {
    import * as stream from "stream";
    import * as events from "events";

// ...
    export function start(options: ReplOptions): events.EventEmitter;
}
```

I would imagine the solution involves defining my own type extending `events.EventEmitter` which has a `context` of type any (object?), and then somehow overriding the definition in `typings/globals/node/index.d.ts` to use the new type.

Is this right? How is it done? (I would imagine you leave `typings/globals/node/index.d.ts` alone and add another file somewhere (probably outside `typings` directory)).

Does the order in which Typescript read these definition files (`index.d.ts` and the one which overrides this definitions) matter?

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

I ended up trying what I had in mind and it's working (but it depends on directory naming... i.e. a hack).

I added `typings2/node/index.d.ts` with the following:

```
declare module "repl" {
    import * as events from "events";

    interface ReplEventEmitter extends events.EventEmitter {
      context: any;
    }

    export function start(options: ReplOptions): ReplEventEmitter;
  }
```

It works fine (i.e. previous definitions are kept and a `context` is added), but it depends on the directory I put it in being named something which comes **after** `typings`.

I'm using Atom and the plugin I'm using automatically changes the "files" field in `tsconfig.json` to list the files to be included for compilation.

If my file comes before `typings/globals/node/index.d.ts` in "files" (managed by Atom plugin), this doesn't work. It needs to come after it (otherwise, this takes effect: `export function start(options: ReplOptions): events.EventEmitter;`).

What's the "proper" way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the "proper" way of doing this?

External module definitions suffer from getting *locked*. If `context` is something is supported, suggest you make a PR to the original definition file.

## Alternative

Create a local copy of the `typings` file and no long depend on the upstream version. I do this as well : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/tree/master/src/typings

Still better than JavaScript (no help at all).

Comment: thanks for the link (didn't know about alm). Getting "locked" means you cannot extend it? So basically, most of the time you'll be maintaining your own type definitions of libraries you use (as fully typing them seems hard). At least until PRs are merged. Ok... fair enough. Yes still better than JS when you want types :)